# Why do we need header files in C when we can use 'extern' identifiers?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, header

My understanding is that when linking, if symbols are declared with 'extern' keyword, then the compiler will not complain the absence of its definition. Furthermore linker either will not have any problem since it will create the symbol table at first and later will detect the proper source code and will fill its defintion.

It seems that there are no problems at all when building a program composed of multiple files without header files - if all the symbols absent in one file are well declared with 'extern'.

If recognitions of symbols of other files can be detected with 'extern' keyword, then why should there be the 'header' files?

Comment: After you have written a couple of hundred `extern` declarations, you realize that one of the functions will have to change its parameters. If there only was a way to make this change in a single place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that when linking, if symbols are declared with 'extern' keyword, then the compiler will not complain the absence of its definition.

The `extern` keyword in C tells the compiler that the declaration it is in describes identifiers but does not define them.<sup>1</sup> This is a compile-time effect, not something that happens when linking.

> If recognitions of symbols of other files can be detected with 'extern' keyword, then why should there be the 'header' files?

Putting declarations in a header files allows us to include them in multiple source files without retyping them or copying and pasting them. That avoids typing errors and helps ensure the same declaration is used for an identifier throughout a program. Further, it is good practice to include the header file that declares identifiers in the source file that defines them, so that the compiler sees both the declaration and the definition in the same compilation and will warn if they are inconsistent.

Another reason is that the header file is considered to be something published by the author of the related source file(s) to tell other programmers what the source files provide. Before a programmer could write their own declarations with `extern` in their own source files, somebody would have to tell them what those declarations are. The person who writes source file NiftyLibrary.c could (and should) write a manual listing all the declarations of the functions (and what those functions do), and then anybody using NiftyLibrary.c could read the manual and type the necessary declarations into their program. But it is easier if the library author provides NiftyLibrary.h and other programmers merely include the header instead of retyping everything.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> This is one of the functions of `extern`. The full semantics are complicated due to the history of C development.

Answer (score 3):

The function prototypes are indeed defined in the C Standard, so instead of getting them from the standard headers, one could just write them in the source code before use.  Conversely, header files also define structures, types and macros that may differ from one system to another or depend on compiler or library configuration.  For these, the standard headers are the only reliable source.

For example, the classic program **hello.c** could be written portably without any standard header inclusion:

```
extern int printf(const char *format, ...);

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Of course the prototype must be compatible with the actual implementation, otherwise you get undefined behavior when running the program even if it compiles without any errors. A compatible prototype is:

```
  extern int printf(const char format[], ...);
```

But defining `printf` as `extern int printf(const char *format);` is incorrect even of you never call the function with more than a single string argument.

Conversely, if you want to open a file with `fopen`, the definition of `FILE` must come from `<stdio.h>`.  Similarly, `malloc` cannot be declared without at least one of the headers that define the type `size_t`.

Comment: Additionally you could declare `extern int printf...` in a way that doesn't corrspond to it's implementation and completly mess things up. E.g (`extern int printf(int foo);...printf(42);...` would compile fine, but during execution you'll get undefined behaviour, (most likely a kind of crash).
`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: yes indeed. I amended the answer with more details.

Comment: Note that the standard explicitly states that such function declarations are permissible: C11 [§7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4) _Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header._